# Facing issues with dropdown button in Flask

Tags: javascript, html, css, dropdown, eventhandler

I am building a basic search page in Flask.

When the page loads, I enter the search bar and get the results.
Then when I click on the drop-down, I can only select 1st option, "Organization" & not the 2nd option "Domain".

Additionally, after the I select the 1st drop-down option, the backend query also gives me errors.
Below are the console logs screenshots:

Successful results
[image]

Errors
[image]
Relevant  code snippets:
HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/6.3.0/css/all.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="templates/static/styles.css">
    <script src="templates/static/script.js"></script>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="templates/images/favicon.ico">
    <img src="templates/images/company.png" alt="Website Logo" class="logo">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="heading">TITLE</h1>

    <div class="search-bar">
        <!-- Dropdown Start -->
        <div class ="dropdown">
            <div id="drop-text" class ="dropdown-text">
                <span id="span">Organization</span>
                <i id="icon" class="fas fa-chevron-down"></i>
            </div>
            <ul id="list" class="dropdown-list">
                <li id="search_term_1" class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="selectOption(this)">Organization</li>
                <li id="search_term_2" class="dropdown-list-item" onclick="selectOption(this)">Domain</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- Dropdown End --> 
  
        <!-- Search box input start -->
        <div class="search-box">
            <input type="search" id="search-input" placeholder="Search..." />
            <i class="fas fa-magnifying-glass" onclick="search()"></i>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div id="resultContainer" class="floating-table">
        <div id="spinner" class="loader"></div>
        <div id="count"></div>
        <button id="btn" onclick="exportToCsv()" title="Download data as CSV." class="btn"><i class="fa fa-download"></i> Download</button>
        <div id="results" class="resultsTable"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="myModal" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <span class="close" onclick="closeModal()">&times;</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; 2024 company, Inc. All rights reserved.</p>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript

```
var searchResult = null;

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let dropdownBtn = document.getElementById("drop-text");
  let list = document.getElementById("list");
  let icon = document.getElementById("icon");
  let span = document.getElementById("span");
  let input = document.getElementById("search-input");
  let listItems = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown-list-item");
  
  // show dropdown list on click on dropdown btn
  dropdownBtn.onclick = function(event){

    event.preventDefault();
    //rotate arrow icon
    if(list.classList.contains('show')){
        icon.style.rotate = "0deg";
    }else{
    icon.style.rotate = "-180deg";
    }
    list.classList.toggle("show");
  }
  
  //hide dropdown list when clicked outside dropdown btn
  window.onclick = function(e){
    if(
        e.target.id !== "drop-text" &&
        e.target.id !== "span" &&
        e.target.id !== "icon" 
    ){
        list.classList.remove("show");
        icon.style.rotate = "0deg";
    }
    };

  for(item of listItems){
    item.onclick = function(e){
      // change dropdown btn txt on click on selected item
      span.innerText = e.target.innerText;
  
      // change input placeholder text and input id based on selected list item
      if (e.target.innerText == "Organization") {
        input.placeholder = "Search Organization...";
        input.setAttribute("id", "search_term_1")
      }
      else if(e.target.innerText == "Domain") {
        input.placeholder = "Search Domain...";
        input.setAttribute("id", "search_term_2")
      }
      input.placeholder = "Search " + e.target.innerText + "..."
      }
  }
});

function formatDateToCustomString(date) {
    const year = date.getFullYear();
    const month = ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    const day = ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
    const hours = ('0' + date.getHours()).slice(-2);
    const minutes = ('0' + date.getMinutes()).slice(-2);

    return `${year}${month}${day}${hours}${minutes}`;
}

const currentDate = new Date();
const formattedDate = formatDateToCustomString(currentDate);

const filename = `search_${formattedDate}`;

function selectOption(option) {
  // Deselect all list items
  document.querySelectorAll('.dropdown-list-item').forEach(item => {
      item.classList.remove('active');
  });

  // Add the 'active' class to the clicked option
  option.classList.add('active');

  // Update search input placeholder and ID
  const selectedText = option.innerText;
  document.getElementById("search-input").placeholder = `Search ${selectedText}...`;
  document.getElementById("search-input").setAttribute("id", `search_term_${selectedText === "Organization" ? 1 : 2}`);

  // If "Domain" is selected, trigger search
  if (selectedText === "Domain") {
      search(); // Modify to handle domain search
  }
}


function search() {
    // Show the loading spinner
    document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'block';

    // Initialize search terms
    var search_term_1 = null;
    var search_term_2 = null;
    var search_term_3 = null;

    // Get the search input element
    var input = document.getElementById("search-input");
    console.log("Input element:", input);

    // Dynamically capture search term based on selected dropdown option
    var selectedOption = document.querySelector(".dropdown-list-item.active");
    console.log("Selected option:", selectedOption);

    if (selectedOption && selectedOption.innerText === "Organization") {
        search_term_1 = input.value;
        input.value = ""; 
    } else if (selectedOption && selectedOption.innerText === "Domain") {
        search_term_2 = input.value;
        input.value = ""; 
    } else if (selectedOption && selectedOption.innerText === "NA") {
      search_term_3 = input.value;
      input.value = ""; 
    } 
    else {
        // If no dropdown item is selected, assume Organization
        search_term_1 = input.value;
        input.value = ""; // Clear the input
    }

    // Make a POST request to your Flask server
    fetch('/search', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({ search_term_1: search_term_1, search_term_2: search_term_2 }),
    })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
        // Hide the loading spinner
        document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';

        // Display the count at the top
        var countDiv = document.getElementById('count');
        var totalCount = data.total_count ? data.total_count : 'unknown';
        countDiv.innerHTML = `<p>${data.count} of ${totalCount} records found</p>`;

        // Update the #results div with the received data
        var resultsDiv = document.getElementById('results');
        resultsDiv.innerHTML = '';

        // Create a table element
        var table = document.createElement('table');
        table.border = '1';
        table.style.backgroundColor = '#ffffffcc';


        // Specify the order of columns
        var columnOrder = ['Base Domain', 'Serial Number', 'SAN', 'Org Name', 'Org Country', 'Valid From', 'Valid To', 'Product Type', 'CA Owner', ];

        // Create table header row
        var headerRow = table.insertRow();
        columnOrder.forEach(columnName => {
        var headerCell = document.createElement('th');
        headerCell.innerHTML = columnName;
        headerCell.style.color = 'lightblue';
        headerRow.appendChild(headerCell);
        });

        // Create table rows with data
        data.results.forEach(result => {
            var row = table.insertRow();
            Object.values(result).forEach(value => {
                var cell = row.insertCell();
                cell.innerHTML = value;
                cell.style.fontSize = '12px';
            });
        });

        // Append the table to the resultsDiv
        resultsDiv.appendChild(table);

        // Store the search result
        searchResult = data;

        // Show the download button
        document.getElementById('btn').style.display = 'block';
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // Hide the loading spinner in case of an error
        document.getElementById('spinner').style.display = 'none';
        console.error('Error:', error);
    });
}
```

CSS

```
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@100;200;300;400;500&display=swap");

:root {
  --blue: #9ab3f5;
  --purple: #9a1663;
  --white: #ffffff;
  --shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) 0px 5px 15px 0px;
}

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-family: Roboto-Light,sans-serif;
}

body {
    font-family: Roboto-Light,sans-serif;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    margin: 0;
    padding-left: 50px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 50px;
    font-stretch: normal;
    background-color: #e6eaec;
}

footer {
    display: block;
    bottom:0;
    justify-content: center;
  }

.search-bar {
  display: flex;
  align-content: center;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background-color: var(--white);
  margin: 2rem auto;
  width: 40%;
}


.dropdown{
  position: relative;
  width: 280px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  border: 1px solid var(--white);
  background-color: #0074c3;
  box-shadow: var(--shadow);
  cursor: pointer;
}

.dropdown-text{
 display: flex;
 align-items: center;
 justify-content: space-between;
 font-size: 1rem;
 font-weight: 500;
 color: var(--white);
 padding: 1rem 1.5rem;
}

.dropdown-list{
  position: absolute;
  top: 4rem;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: var(--white);
  transition: max-height 0.5s;
}

#list.show{
  max-height: 300px;
}

.dropdown-list-item{
  font-size: 0.9rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  padding: 0.9rem 0 1rem 1.5rem;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: margin-left 0.2s ease,color 0.2s ease;
}
.dropdown-list-item:hover{
  margin-left: 0.5rem;
  color: #0074c3;
}

.search-box{
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-right: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  color: #0074c3;
}

.search-box input{
  padding: 1rem;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  border: 0;
  outline: 0;
}

.search-box i{
  font-size: 1.3rem;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.search-box input::placeholder{
  font-size: 1rem;
  font-weight: 500;
}

/* Darker background on mouse-over */
#btn:hover {
background-color: #037ed0;
color: white;
 }

#btn {
  display: none;
  border: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  height: 37px;
  width: 9%;
  background-color: #0074c3;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 15px;
  margin-right: -10px;
  transition-duration: 50ms;
  cursor: pointer;
}

 #resultsLink {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    top: 45px;
    right: 500px;
}

#count {
  top: 45px;
  position: relative;
}

.footer {
    /* position: fixed; */
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
    color: #6a6767; /* Match the text color from Digicert.com */
    font-size: 14px; /* Adjust the font size as needed */
}

.heading {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    margin-top: 33.5px;
    color: #0074c3;
    font-family: FjallaOne-Regular,sans-serif;
  }

.floating-table {
    /* margin: 20px; */
    border-radius: 10px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.exportButton {
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}

.floating-table button {
    border: 1px;
    display: inline-block;
    overflow: hidden;
    color: white;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 40px;
    right: 50px;
    }

.resultsTable{
  padding-top: 50px;
}

#resultsTable {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

#results th, #results td {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    color: #333333;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 6px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

#results th {
    background-color: #f2f2f2 !important;
    color: #0074c3 !important;
    font-size: 106% !important;
    font-weight: bold !important;
}

#results td {
  font-size: 12px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
  padding: 6px;
  width: auto;
}

input[readonly] {
    background-color: #f2f2f2; /* Light gray background */
    color: #999; /* Gray text color */
    cursor: not-allowed; /* Change cursor to not-allowed */
}

.loader {
    border: 8px solid #f3f3f3;
    border-top: 8px solid #0074c3;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    animation: spin 1s linear infinite;
    margin: 20px auto;
    display: none;
}

@keyframes spin {
    0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }
    100% { transform: rotate(360deg); }
}

.instruction-box {
    margin-top: 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 11.15%;
    bottom: 68%;
    right: 21px;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.6);
    padding: 4px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    max-width: 515px;
    max-height: 515px;
}

.modal {
    display: none;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100% !important;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
}

/* Modal content */
.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto;
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50% !important;
}

/* Close button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.logo {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: -25px;
    /* margin-right: auto; */
    width: 30%;
    max-width: 180px;
    height: auto;
    padding-top: 20px;
    position: absolute;
  }

.form-container {
margin-top: 20px;
display: flex;
justify-content: center;
}

.form-container input[type=text] {
padding: 10px;
border: 1px solid #a2a0a0;
border-radius: 5px;
width: 30%;
height: 40px;
font-size: 17px;
margin-right: 10px;
}

.form-container input[type=text]:focus {
outline: none;
border-color: #0074c3;
}

.form-container input[type=text]::placeholder {
    opacity: 0.4;
}

.form-container button {
border: 2px;
border-radius: 5px;
background-color: #0074c3;
color: white;
height: 40px;
width: 12%;
font-size: 17px;
margin-right: 6px;
cursor: pointer;
}

.form-container button:hover {
background-color: #0074c3;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the menu and the logo stack on top of each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .logo {
        width: 100%;
    }

    .search-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .search-container input[type=text], .search-container button {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 0;
    }

    .form-container {
        flex-direction: column;
    }

    .form-container input[type=text], .form-container button {
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: 10px;
        margin-right: 0;
    }
}
```